# Google App Engine PHP error

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am programing in php with Google App Engine launcher

The code is just reading data from Google Spreadsheet, my output in the localhost is just blank. When looked in GAELauncher Log

Its like:

```
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
stdout:
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.32
Content-type: text/html

name = name = 1 stderr:

INFO     2014-12-18 15:26:44,693 module.py:718] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 16
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
stdout:
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.32
Content-type: text/html

name = name = 1 stderr:

INFO     2014-12-18 15:26:46,017 module.py:718] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 16
```

I dont know what to do. So please provide me some help or advidse

Comment: Please share your app.yaml and the corresponding php script.

Comment: @Mars check my code below....